# How do moving iron meters work on AC current?

Tags: ac, measurement, meter

I read on the internet that an iron vane is attracted to a coil and the vanr is attached to a pointer. Thus we get the reading.

The article also said that we can measure both AC and DC using it.

How is that done? Won't the vane keep oscillating when connected to AC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coil will attract the iron on both the positive and negative halves of the sine wave, so no rectification is required in a moving iron meter.  A lump of iron is attracted to a magnet whatever the polarity of the magnet.

The needle doesn't oscillate because the iron and the needle are too heavy to move noticeably in 1/100 or 1/120 second.  The mass of the iron provides a degree of damping to the meter.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

The moving iron part is attracted by an electromagnet and the current through the electromagnet determines the physical pull/force on that iron. The polarity of the AC current has no importance; just like a piece of iron is attracted to a magnet irrespective of whether the north pole is closest or the south pole.

Both half cycles of the AC current will attract the magnet.

> *Won't the vane keeps oscillating when connected to AC?*

If the moving iron part were in fact magnetized, then polarity would make a big difference but, it isn't magnetized hence it is attracted on both half cycles of the AC waveform.

- [What does the moving iron voltmeter measure in a circuit, average voltage or RMS voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102235/what-does-the-moving-iron-voltmeter-measure-in-a-circuit-average-voltage-or-rms/102240#102240)
- [What is the reason that moving iron instrument can measure both AC and DC but moving coil instrument can't?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/428799/what-is-the-reason-that-moving-iron-instrument-can-measure-both-ac-and-dc-but-mo/428838#428838)

Comment: Oh. I missed it. I wanted to give both the answer the green tick. Sorry that I gave the other answer because he has a lesser reputation. Sorry. And thank you.